# Why is the play framework not built on top of the Servlet API?

Tags: java, servlets, playframework

I started playing with the playframework recently and really enjoy the simplicity.

But one nagging question I've had is why it eschews the servlet specification all together? What was the main motivation behind such an architectural decision?

Answer (score 13):

From the [FAQ](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.2/faq)

> We are fully aware that we made
>   choices that are pretty uncommon in
>   the Java world, and that Play does not
>   blindly follow all the so-called Java
>   ‘good practices’. But all of the Play
>   team members are very experienced Java
>   developers and we are totally aware of
>   the choices we made and the rules we
>   broke.
>
> Java itself is a very generic
>   programming language and not
>   originally designed for web
>   application development. It is a very
>   different thing to write a generic and
>   reusable Java library and to create a
>   web application. A web application
>   itself doesn’t need to be designed to
>   be reusable. You need less
>   abstraction, less configuration.
>   Reusability does exist for web
>   applications, but through web service
>   APIs rather than language-level
>   integration.
>
> When the development time tends to
>   zero you can concentrate on your
>   application features and experiment
>   quickly, instead of trying to abstract
>   things for future developments.

Play! applications can be deployed as web application on other web server containers, but it is mainly designed as a full stack framework; Play *is* the platform. And, in my opinion, this is what makes it beautiful and fast.

Comment: How is this specifically related to the servlet api?

Comment: You asked: "What was the main motivation behind such an architectural decision?", and I responded : "Play *is* the platform". They didn't just want to make it a framework, or some container, but rather a full stack application, including Web server and all. The bottom line is that you just can't compare Play with the servlet specification because apart from being Java, they do not share much in common (if not at all).

Comment: Not sure I follow you. First of all, Play is a framework - software system that is extensible and clearly documents those extensions points. Secondly I am not comparing play with servlets (that would be silly) I am asking why leave out servlet API.

Comment: Play is not only a framework, as stated under the question "Why don’t you rename the ‘play’ package to ‘org.playframework’?!" in the FAQ, and I'm saying that Play and servlets are two different things; why would it try to borrow another unrelated project's specification? What would you think could be the advantages?